# how to hook Entity creation to login action in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am building my first Symfony project. My user authentication is against an Active Directory via LDAP. When the user logs in, I want to check if there is a record in the `person` table of a MySQL db and create one if there is not. This should be the only time when a new person record can be added.

I'm using the Doctrine package to deal with the database. I've generated a `Person` entity which is essentially just a one-to-one mapping of the Active Directory GUID to an autoincremented primary key. Here is the entity class:

```
namespace MyProject\PersonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $AD_guid;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set AD_guid
     *
     * @param string $aDGuid
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setADGuid($aDGuid)
    {
        $this->AD_guid = $aDGuid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get AD_guid
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getADGuid()
    {
        return $this->AD_guid;
    }
}
```

I *think* that coupling `Person` creation with the login action should either mean that `Person` doesn't get a `PersonController` (since it is never presented), or perhaps that the `PersonController` does not require routing directions. But whether I have a `PersonController` or not, I'm unsure how to hook in to the login action. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

How do you authenticate a user? Do you use a plugin for LDAP auth or did you write it on your own?
Either way there is a class and method checking the user in LDAP.
Hook a) inside this class, b) after parent call of this class.
Just check if there is an entry inside your database and if not, make a new Person(), set the data and save() it. Person is your Model and can be used anywhere you need (though you should respect MVC patterns)

Comment: I'm using the `ZtecSecurityActiveDirectoryBundle` (https://github.com/ztec/ZtecSecurityActiveDirectoryBundle) for authentication. But my impression is that Symfony abstracts Security so that I should be able to put a `Listener` on the login event regardless of which authenticator bundle I use. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Maybe this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114592/symfony-2-custom-user-provider-form-login